# Laravel 5.3 middleware callback function in controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel, callback, laravel-5.3, middleware

as mentioned in the documentation of Laravel 5.3 i am trying to add a middleware callback in the constructor of a controller

> Controller's also allow you to register middleware using a Closure.
>   This provides a convenient way to define a middleware for a single
>   controller without defining an entire middleware class:

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    // ...
    return $next($request);
});
```

unfortunately i am getting the error:

> Illegal offset type

which is logical because the middleware method of the Illuminate\Routing\Controller class accepts a the first param as an array only, i am not confused why would they add this code sample to the documentation although its not gonna work, or am I doing something wrong or missing something ?

[documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controllers-and-namespaces)

Comment: can you add your own code or more of it?

Comment: `Illuminate\Routing\Controller@middleware` accepts `$middleware` (which can be a `array|string|\Closure`) as it's first param. Are you definitely using at least Laravel 5.3.4 ? You can check this by running `php artisan --version`.

Comment: i always thought i was using the last version of laravel, i just checked the composer.json file and you are right it was requiring "laravel/framework": "5.3" only i added the very important .* at the end and ran composer update

works great.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

the laravel version should be at least:

> 5.3.4